# Exact (optimal) solution with pywrapcp library (or tools)

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing, cp-sat

I am new to using `pywrapcp` library to solve vehicle routing problems, but I am well acquainted with `cpsat` solver. So, for a vehicle routing problem, I thought to put to use `cpsat` solver rather than the routing specific library because of the additional learning overhead.

I looked at the below vehicle routing problem with pickup and delivery, already solved in or tools webpage:
https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery

I expressed the exact problem (same data) in `cpsat` solver, and got an optimal solution. Now, I wanted to check if my formulation / code is correct, so I decided to match the solution of `cpsat` with `pywrapcp` library, but found that with `pywrapcp` we are getting a heuristic solution (albeit a good one). With `cpsat`, I have got an exact solution.

So the question is how can we get an optimal solution with `pywrapcp` ?

`pywrapcp` reports the below solution:

```
Route for vehicle 0:
 0 ->  13 ->  15 ->  11 ->  12 -> 0
Distance of the route: 1552m

Route for vehicle 1:
 0 ->  5 ->  2 ->  10 ->  16 ->  14 ->  9 -> 0
Distance of the route: 2192m

Route for vehicle 2:
 0 ->  4 ->  3 -> 0
Distance of the route: 1392m

Route for vehicle 3:
 0 ->  7 ->  1 ->  6 ->  8 -> 0
Distance of the route: 1780m
```

So the maximum distance travelled by a vehicle = 2192

With `cpsat` formulation, I get the following:

```
# vehicle : [node_list, distance]
{0: [[0, 4, 3, 15, 11, 0], 2032],
 1: [[0, 10, 2, 8, 7, 0], 1940],
 2: [[0, 13, 16, 14, 12, 0], 2008],
 3: [[0, 9, 5, 6, 1, 0], 1940]}
```

maximum distance travelled by a vehicle = 2032

So, `cpsat` reports the optimal solution which is lower than `pywrapcp`, but how to confirm this with `pywrapcp` ?

Below is my formulation with `cpsat` solver. The code it works fine, but any improvements are welcome.

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

locations = range(17)

data = [
    # fmt: off
  [0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354, 468, 776, 662],
  [548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674, 1016, 868, 1210],
  [776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164, 1130, 788, 1552, 754],
  [696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822, 1164, 560, 1358],
  [582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708, 1050, 674, 1244],
  [274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628, 514, 1050, 708],
  [502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856, 514, 1278, 480],
  [194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320, 662, 742, 856],
  [308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662, 320, 1084, 514],
  [194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388, 274, 810, 468],
  [536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764, 730, 388, 1152, 354],
  [502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114, 308, 650, 274, 844],
  [388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194, 536, 388, 730],
  [354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0, 342, 422, 536],
  [468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536, 342, 0, 764, 194],
  [776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274, 388, 422, 764, 0, 798],
  [662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730, 536, 194, 798, 0],
    # fmt: on
]

distance_matrix = {}
for i in locations:
    for j in locations:
        distance_matrix[(i, j)] = data[i][j]

num_vehicles = 4

pickups_deliveries = [
    [1, 6],
    [2, 10],
    [4, 3],
    [5, 9],
    [7, 8],
    [15, 11],
    [13, 12],
    [16, 14],
]

depot = 0

model = cp.CpModel()

# Build decision variables :
dv = {}
for i in locations:
    for j in locations:
        for k in range(num_vehicles):
            dv[(i, j, k)] = model.NewBoolVar("from_%i_to_%i_vehc_%i" % (i, j, k))

route_length = {}
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    route_length[k] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, "")

for k in range(num_vehicles):
    model.Add(
        route_length[k]
        == sum(dv[i, j, k] * distance_matrix[i, j] for i in locations for j in locations)
    )

# =============================================================================
#  Objective function
# =============================================================================
# minimize the length of the longest single route among all vehicles
max_route_length = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, "max_route_length")
model.AddMaxEquality(max_route_length, [route_length[k] for k in route_length])
model.Minimize(max_route_length)

# =============================================================================
# CONSTRAINTS :
# =============================================================================

# 1. Vehicle leaves node that it enters
for j in locations:
    for k in range(num_vehicles):
        model.Add(
            sum(dv[i, j, k] for i in locations) == sum(dv[j, i, k] for i in locations)
        )

# 2. Ensure that every node is entered once
for j in locations[1:]:
    model.Add(sum(dv[i, j, k] for k in range(num_vehicles) for i in locations) == 1)


# 3. Every vehicle leaves the depot
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    model.Add(sum(dv[0, j, k] for j in locations[1:]) == 1)


# 4. Capacity constraint
# No capacity constraint here

# 5. no travel from a node to itself
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    for i in locations:
        model.Add(dv[i, i, k] == 0)

# 5. time windows constraints
# these are created to enforce precedences amongst the nodes

time_wind = {}
for i in locations:
    time_wind[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, "start_node_%i" % i)

model.Add(time_wind[0] == 0)


# =============================================================================
# # sub-tour elimination
# =============================================================================

# list of nodes that a vehicle visits
dv_vehc_node_bin = {}
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    lst = {}
    for i in locations[1:]:
        lst[i] = model.NewBoolVar("vehc_%i_node_%i" % (k, i))
    dv_vehc_node_bin[k] = lst

# whether a node was visited by a vehicle or not
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    for i in locations[1:]:
        model.AddMaxEquality(
            dv_vehc_node_bin[k][i],
            [dv[i, j, k] for j in locations] + [dv[j, i, k] for j in locations],
        )

# if [1, 6] is one of the precedence
# then both the nodes have to be visited by the same vehicle
# so if a vehicle visits 1, it has to visit 6, if not 1 then not 6
for p in pickups_deliveries:
    for k in range(num_vehicles):
        model.AddImplication(dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[0]], dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[1]])
        model.AddImplication(dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[1]], dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[0]])

        model.AddImplication(
            dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[0]].Not(), dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[1]].Not()
        )
        model.AddImplication(
            dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[1]].Not(), dv_vehc_node_bin[k][p[0]].Not()
        )

# enforcing the precedences
for p in pickups_deliveries:
    model.Add(time_wind[p[0]] < time_wind[p[1]])

# eliminating sub-tours using AddCircuit constraint
arcs_dict = {}
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    arcs_list = []
    for i in locations:
        for j in locations:
            if (i == j) & (i == 0):
                arcs_list.append([0, 0, dv[0, 0, k]])
            elif (i == j) & (i > 0):
                lit = model.NewBoolVar("vehc_%i_node_%i" % (k, i))
                model.AddImplication(dv_vehc_node_bin[k][i], lit.Not())
                model.AddImplication(dv_vehc_node_bin[k][i].Not(), lit)
                arcs_list.append([i, i, lit])
            else:
                arcs_list.append([i, j, dv[(i, j, k)]])
    arcs_dict[k] = arcs_list

for a in arcs_dict:
    model.AddCircuit(arcs_dict[a])

solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
status = solver.Solve(model)

print(solver.ResponseStats())

# output the solution
path_dict = {}
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    path = [y for y, v in distance_matrix.items() if solver.Value(dv[y[0], y[1], k]) > 0]
    distance = 0
    for p in path:
        distance += distance_matrix[p[0], p[1]]

    i = 0
    lst = [0]
    nxt = 10000
    while nxt != 0:
        nxt = 0 if i == 0 else nxt
        nxt = [j for i, j in path if i == nxt][0]
        lst.append(nxt)
        i += 1

    path_dict[k] = [lst, distance]
```

Comment: The routing solver is not exact! You can plug in the solution from cp-sat as [initial_solution](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/main/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_initial_routes.py) and verify it.

Comment: Thanks much. I was able to pass the cpsat solution as an initial solution, and everything worked well.

So essentially, if for relatively small sized problems, if we are looking for provably optimal solutions then cpsat is a better option.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/inria-UFF/VRPSolverEasy) is a good exact solver for VRP that you can have a look at!

Comment: Hey, thanks much!